# How to convert the following Meijer G function to hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions

$$
G_{1,4}^{2,0}\left(z\left|\begin{smallmatrix}1\\
0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)
$$

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with.  Splitting the problem statement between the title and the body can be difficult for Readers to parse.  The body of the Question provides ample space for the problem to be accompanied by *context*, such as why the problem is interesting or difficult, or what simplification you've already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I got from *Mathematica*
$$G_{1,4}^{2,0}\left(z\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\left[3\gamma -4 z \, _2F_4\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},2,2;-z\right)+\log 16z \right]$$

Hope it helps

Edit.

Mathematica code

```
MeijerG[{{},{1}},{{0,0},{1/2,1/2}},z]//FunctionExpand
```